Matrix representations of linear maps: Problem when one of the vector spaces has dimension zero
A related question has been asked before, but my question goes beyond it.
Let $V, W$ be vector spaces over a ground field $F$, $n = \dim V, m = \dim W$, and let $b = (b_1,\ldots,b_n)$ be an ordered basis for $V$, $c = (c_1,\ldots,c_m)$ be an ordered basis for $W$.
It is well-known that each linear map $f : V \to W$ can be represented with respect to the bases $b$ and $c$ by an $(m \times n)$-matrix $M(f) = (f_{ij})$ with entries in $F$  determined by
$$f(b_j) = \sum_{i=1}^mf_{ij} c_i . \tag{1}$$
It is also well-known that
$$M(g \circ f) = M(g)\cdot M(f) \tag{2}$$
where $\cdot$ denotes matrix multiplication.
This is what one can find in all textbooks that I know. However, it seems that the implicit assumption in all books is that $n > 0$ and $m > 0$.
What happens if $n = 0$ or $m = 0$?
In this case the zero map is the only linear map $V \to W$. But what is an $(m \times n)$-matrix if $n= 0$ or $m=0$?
Formally an $(m \times n)$-matrix is a function $M : \underline m \times \underline n \to F$, where we use the abbreviation $\underline p = \{ x \in \mathbb N \mid 1 \le x \le p\}$. Thus, if $n = 0$ or $m = 0$, then $\underline m \times \underline n = \emptyset$ and there exists exactly one function $E : \emptyset \to F$ which we can denote as the empty matrix. It is the same matrix for all pairs $(m,n)$ such that $n= 0$ of $m=0$. The only textbook where I found this concept is Bourbaki's Algebra I Chapter II §10 Section 1 "Definition of Matrices". Unfortunately the treatment of matrix representations of linear maps (Section 4 "Matrices and Linear Maps") does not cover the above situation.
$(1)$ works nicely with the empty matrix.

If $n = 0$ (i.e. $V = 0$), then we do not at all need formula $(1)$ because the zero map is the only linear map $0 \to W$.

If $m = 0$ (i.e. $W = 0$) and $n > 0$, then again the zero map is the only linear map $V \to 0$. Anyway, for each basis element $b_j$ we get a representation of $f(b_j)$ via $(1)$ (with the empty matrix!) as an empty sum which has value $0$.


However, formula $(2)$ is no longer true. The problem is the empty matrix $E$.
Consider two linear maps $f : V \to W, g : W \to X$.

If $V=0$, then $M(f) = E$ and $M(g \circ f) = E$. If we define $A \cdot E = E$ for all matrices $A$ (which is also intuitively the correct choice), then $(2)$ is satisfied.

If $X=0$, then $M(g) = E$ and $M(g \circ f) = E$. If we define $E \cdot A = E$ for all matrices $A$, then $(2)$ is again satisfied.

If $W = 0$ and $V,X \ne 0$, we get a problem. It seems plausible to define $E \cdot E = E$ (as suggested by the two above cases), but let us write $E' = E \cdot E$. Since $g \circ f : V \to X$ is the zero map, $M(g \circ f)$ is the zero matrix (which is non-empty!). But $M(g) \cdot M(f) = E \cdot E = E'$. Whatever $E'$ is, it cannot be the zero matrix for all non-zero $V,W$.


Here are my questions:

Does any textbook treat the case $n= 0$ or $m = 0$?

Can the failure of $(2)$ be repaired somehow?



For the second part it is not a failure: write your coefficient as formal sums, then summing on an empty set is zero. I believe you should always use these formal sums you’ll see that it checks out

You can define a matrix to be a triple $(m,n,f)$ such that $m, n$ are natural numbers, and $f : \underline m \times \underline n \to F$. Now matrices "remember" their dimensions, so the $3\times 0$ matrix is not equal to the $0\times 2$ matrix. This is a common trick in set theory based category theory to make the homsets disjoint.

If I understand, the reason why you say that formula $(2)$ breaks is that, if the definitinon of matrix is a function from $\underline m\times \underline n\to F$, the matrix $E$ is simply defined as a function from the empty set to $F$, so there is no information on the size of the matrix (whether $0\times n$, $m\times 0$, or $0\times 0$). So the product $E\cdot E$ is not well-defined, or if defined, it cannot be the zero matrix in all dimensions at the same time.
The obvious way I see to fix this issue is to include the information on the size of the matrix inside the matrix itself. So, we could give a new definition.
Definition. A matrix is a triple $\mathbf A=(A,m,n)$, where $m,n$ are natural numbers, and $A:\underline m\times \underline n\to F$ is a function. The product of two matrices $\mathbf A=(A,l,m), \mathbf B=(B,m,n)$ is defined as
$$ \mathbf C=\mathbf A\cdot\mathbf B= (A\cdot B,l,n), $$
where $A\cdot B$ is given by the usual formula
$$ (A\cdot B)_{ij}=\sum_{k=1}^{m}A_{ik}B_{kj}. $$
The numbers $m$ and $n$ will be redundant most of the time, except when $\underline m\times \underline n$ is the empty set.

Whoops, you beat me to it :) I was converting my comments to an answer. +1

Thank you. Do you know any textbook covering this?

Unfortunately not...

Nice answer! In fact, already the use of a phrase like "$(0 \times n)$-matrix" indicates that $(0,n)$ is part of the given data - which cannot be reconstructed from the map living on $\underline 0 \times \underline n = \emptyset$.

Lorenzo Pompili gave an elegant answer. Here is another idea (but to be honest, it is a bit artificial).
For a non-negative integer $x$ let $\underline{\underline{x}} = \{0,1,\ldots, x\}$. This set is never empty. For $m, n \ge 0$ we call a function $A : \underline{\underline{m}} \times \underline{\underline{n}} \to F$ such that $A(i,j) = 0$ for $i = 0$ or $j=0$ an augmented $(m \times n)$-matrix.
Each augmented $(m \times n)$-matrix $A$ contains an ordinary $(m \times n)$-matrix $A_{ord} = A \mid_{\underline m\times \underline n} : \underline m\times \underline n \to F$. That is, we delete row and column  no. $0$ of $A$.
If $m, n > 0$, we can reconstruct $A$ from  $A_{ord}$.
If $m=0$ or $n=0$, then $A_{ord}$ is the empty matrix $E$ and we can't reconstruct $A$ from $E$.
The product $A \cdot B$ of an augmented $(m \times n)$-matrix $A$ and an augmented $(n \times p)$-matrix $B$ is defined as
$$A \cdot B : \underline{\underline{m}} \times \underline{\underline{p}} \to F, (A \cdot B)(i,j) = \sum_{k=0}^n A(i,k)B(k,j) .$$
It is easy to verify that $A \cdot B$ is an augmented $(m \times p)$-matrix. If $m, n, p > 0$, then
$$(A \cdot B)_{ord} = A_{ord} \cdot B_{ord}  . \tag{0}$$
$(0)$ is also true when $m=0$ or $p=0$ if we adopt your convention that $M \cdot E = E \cdot M = E$ for all ordinary matrices $M$.
The "critical case" is $m, p > 0, n = 0$. You can easily check that $A \cdot B$ has all entries $0$, thus $(A \cdot B)_{ord}$ is the ordinary $(m \times p)$-zero-matrix (which is non-empty) whereas $A_{ord} \cdot B_{ord} = E \cdot E$. Thus $(0)$ cannot be satisfied for all $A, B$, whatever the definition of $E \cdot E$ might be.
As in your question we can represent each linear map $f : V \to W$, where $\dim V = n$ and $\dim W = m$, by an augmented $(m \times n)$-matrix $A(f) = (f_{ij})$ via
$$f(b_j) = \sum_{i=1}^mf_{ij} c_i . \tag{1}$$
Note that the entries $f_{0j}$ and $f_{i0}$ (which are $0)$ do not occur in these sums; they only have a formal use.
The benefit of working with augmented matrices is that we get
$$A(g \circ f) = A(g)\cdot A(f) . \tag{2}$$
Just check the "problem case" $W=0$ and $V,X \ne 0$ from your question.

As I was stating in my comment, the (2) does not fail:
Take the classical case: $A$ an $n \times m$ matrix and $B$ an $m \times l$ matrix. Consider $C = AB$, then
$$c_{i,j} = \sum_{k=1}^m a_{i,k}b_{k,j}$$
For $1\leq i \leq n$ and $1\leq j \leq l$.
Now if you set $m = 0$ which corresponds to your case you get
$$c_{i,j} = \sum_{k=1}^0 a_{i,k}b_{k,j}= 0$$
since it is an empty sum!
In fact the E’ you are mentionning is the zero matrix of the right size.
This solves your problem which was not really one at the beginning. The visual notation of the matrix is made for human eyes but it is just a way to represent information. It is indeed misleading when you start to consider extreme cases where you have matrices with empty length but a width.
Now for reference I unfortunately don’t really know, especially in english, however I think that there exists some books about these empty sets or zero cases. Some even talk about the one element field!

Formula $(2)$ requires to define a single matrix $E' = E \cdot E$ which only depends on $E$. As explained by Lorenzo Pompili, $E$ in itself does not contain enough information to give a zero  matrix of the appropriate size. You cannot  choose a single zero-matrix $E'$ which works universally in $(2)$. By the way, I did not downvote.
